# Why does prototype.js interfere with unrelated javascript operations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prototypejs, conflict

Building a website. When I order my  tags like this, LightCycle works but Lightbox doesn't:

**Lightcycle works, Lightbox doesn't:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/prototype.js"></script>
```

When I order it like this, Lightbox works but LightCycle doesn't:

**Lightbox works, LightCycle doesn't:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/prototype.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Frustrating.

Comment: If jQuery.noConflict() hasn't solved the issue, could you provide links to the Lightcycle and Lightbox plugins that you're using. Lightcycle in particular might have a bug whereby it doesn't work properly if $ is in use by another library.

Comment: Sure, no problem CycleLite: http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/lite/

Comment: And the lightbox: http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: The code and jQuery / prototype problems are live here: http://abyy.net

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're having a conflict because both libraries use the $ shortcut.  Look into the noconflict feature of jQuery or the equivalent of prototype.

You can read more here:  http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Answer (score 2):

Because they use the same `$` shorthand.

Try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/prototype.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tried that, it caused the Lightbox to function but not the LightCycle.

Comment: In that case, the LightCycle plugin has not been coded according to the jQuery plugin authoring guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Does a call to `jQuery.noConflict()` fix it? You can also give jQuery an alias within your on functions if you miss the `$` shortcut:

```
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

References:

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

http://samsami2u.wordpress.com/2009/03/14/prototypejs-jqueryjs-conflict-and-resolution/

Answer (score 0):

So using Surreal Dreams recontamination, I implemented this:

```
<script src="./prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script>
     var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

     // Use jQuery via $j(...)
     $j(document).ready(function(){
       $j("div").hide();
     });

     // Use Prototype with $(...), etc.
     $('someid').hide();
   </script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/lightbox.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/chili-1.7.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.lite.1.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    $('#slideshow1').cycle({
        delay: 2000,
        speed: 1000,
    });


});

</script>
```

The next question that springs to mind is what to replace 'someid' with. I'm assuming '#slideshow1'. But what displays when I do this is just a plain black page. Annoying.